# Nginx can't find specific location

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm trying to run django + gunicorn + nginx by using `docker-compose`. 
django and gunicorn now are working correctly and response to request, but, when I try to access to project within nginx (port 80), it can't find my project location. 
following are nginx `Dockerfile` and `nginx.conf`:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.4-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

and `nginx.conf`:

```
upstream back {
    # in docker-compose.yml file, (django+gunicorn) service name is `backend` and is listening on port 8000.
    server backend:8000;    
}

server {

    listen 80;
    location /backend {
        proxy_pass http://back;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Now, gunicorn is listening on port 8000 and responses to requestes. if I go to `127.0.0.1`, I see nginx default page. But if I go to `127.0.0.1/backend/`, nginx shows me 404 page.

in docker-compose logs it shows me following line:

```
[error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/backend" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.176.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /backend HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1" <br>
```

It seems, nginx are searching for `/backend` in his folders in `usr/share` and does not pass request to port 8000.
How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
this is `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    ...

  redis:
    ...

  backend:
    hostname: backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

    volumes:
      - ./backend/app/:/opt/

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile

    working_dir: /opt/app/project
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env

    ports:
     - 8000:8000

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `gunicorn`, but your configuration looks basically correct.

When `nginx` does the `proxy_pass`, the `path` `/backend` is also `proxy_pass`'ed to your `backend`-service.
I assume, that your `gunicorn` does not know how to handle the `/backend`-path?

Maybe it would help, if you rewrite everything to `/`:

`nginx.conf`:

```
upstream back {
    # in docker-compose.yml file, (django+gunicorn) service name is `backend` and is listening on port 8000.
    server backend:8000;    
}

server {

    listen 80;
    location /backend {
        # # # this rewrites all requests to '/backend' to '/' ...
        # # # ... before passing them to your backend-service
        rewrite /backend.* / break;
        # # #
        proxy_pass http://back;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

I've adapted your `docker-compose.yml` for easy testing purposes:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: nginx:alpine
    hostname: backend
    expose:
     - 80

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

`default.conf`:

```
upstream back {
    # in docker-compose.yml file, (django+gunicorn) service name is `backend` and is listening on port 8000.
    server backend:80;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    location /backend {
        rewrite /backend.* / break;
        proxy_pass http://back;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

`docker-compose up`:

```sh
╰─❯ docker-compose up
Starting test_backend_1 ... done
Starting test_nginx_1   ... done
Attaching to test_backend_1, test_nginx_1
backend_1  | 172.21.0.3 - - [03/Apr/2020:11:53:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.64.1" "172.21.0.1"
nginx_1    | 172.21.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2020:11:53:52 +0000] "GET /backend HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.64.1" "-"
```

`curl`:

```sh
╰─❯ curl localhost:8080/backend

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is in nginx. it doesn't pass /backend to any where.